# Continuous deployment to Azure Web App from Bitbucket fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, bitbucket, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

I set up git continuous deployment with bitbucket on my Azure website according to this [blogpost](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/#Step3)

I created a basic mvc 5 app and push to bitbuket. everything going fine.

When i choose continuous deployment from my azure account and choose my project and branch and press ok. after some time it will give me following error [image]

Please help 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have enough empty space on your website?

Answer (score 1):

You have to temporarily raise your plan tier and then revert it back to the free tier after deployment.

It will cost you less than 10 cents.

Comment: This works well, and is cheap. Just remember to switch back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that there is no space left on your device.

Comment: The file system storage under my app shows i just used the 472.21 MB out of 1024 MB.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Azure Web App may simply be out of disk space. What tier is your app in? Note that Free Web Apps get 1 GB of disk space that is shared between all the Web Apps in the Resource Group (details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/)). The Azure Portal should tell you if you are in fact out of disk space.

Comment: The file system storage under my app shows i just used the 472.21 MB out of 1024 MB.

Comment: As I mentioned, this storage is shared between all apps in the resource group, so just looking at this one app is not sufficient. Please use [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to look at your site files and check for free space.